# Como enviar o blob em tempo real?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tem alguma maneira de enviar o blob pro servidor em tempo real (streaming)?
Procurei sobre sockets mas não tive bons resultados...

Comment: Da forma como está a pergunta, é difícil responder, mas creio que o que você procura é ou [WebSockets](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) ou talvez [WebRTC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC) (dependendo da aplicação).

Comment: tem algum exemplo simples de uso de websockets ?

Comment: Pessoalmente, não, nunca usei na prática. Talvez outros possam te ajudar melhor, mas como isso é algo que demanda suporte no lado servidor (i.e. vai além de simples HTTP, é um protocolo à parte), seria bom se indicasse que plataforma você usa.

Answer (score 1):

Use WebSockets para se conectar ao servidor e faça transferência binária. Note que não são todos os navegadores que aceitam modo binário do WebSockets. Um bom começo pra aprender WebSockets é usando Node.js. Talvez eu possa te ajudar mais sobre isso se você especificar melhor sua pergunta.

Comment: Desisti temporariamente de usar websockets por falta de dinheiro, precisa de um plano de hospedagem VPS ou dedicado para rodar o node.js e websockets, estou usando webrtc, mesmo com o problema de compatibilidade de alguns navegadores...

Comment: Você está enganado quanto a precisar de um VPS ou dedicado, pode usar Node.js no seu próprio computador, independente da plataforma. Mas caso queira partir pra algo online mesmo, pode testar o Node.js inclusive usando o OpenShift. https://www.openshift.com/

Comment: Estou confuso usando o OpenShift, como eu rodo os scripts ?

Comment: E como eu rodo localmente o node.js como um servidor?

Comment: Comece baixando o instalador em http://nodejs.org/. Depois de instalado crie um arquivo main.js com o exemplo da página inicial do site e rode em um terminal com node main.js. Com relação ao OpenShift, melhor criar outra pergunta com esta tag.

Comment: mas qual seria o link para acessar o js rodando no node.js ? meu ip?

Comment: no brasil acho que não dá mais pra usar o ip como servidor, ou dá ?